# simple Apache RewriteCond and RewriteRule issue

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite

I'm trying to follow https://github.com/crwilliams/diary-user-interface/wiki/cachebusting

If I set my HTML code to:

```
  href="/myDir/myFile.2013103000.html"
```

and add to .htaccess:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
  RewriteEngine on
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
  RewriteRule ^(.+)\.(\d+)\.(html)$ $1.$3 [L]
</IfModule>
```

I see "Page not found" error as the browser goes to: `https://www.mycompany.com/myDir/myFile.2013103000.html`

Any idea what could be happening?

What can I do to trouble shoot?

Sitting at the webpage with the link, if I change .htaccess to this:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
   RewriteEngine on
   RewriteRule ^(.+) https://www.mycompany.com/myDir/myFile.html [L]  
</IfModule>
```

and then click the link it works (but obviously this just for troubleshooting).

UPDATE

Here's the complete .htaccess file in case something following the above can be identified as the problem:

```
# attempt to implement version control with cachebusting
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule ^(.+)\.(\d+)\.(html)$ $1.$3 [L]
</IfModule>

# Pruning irrelevant parts (Phil)

# force SSL and www
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^mycompany\.com$ [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !on
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.mycompany.com/$1 [R=301,L]

# Redirect index.html to a specific subfolder;
Redirect permanent /index.html https://www.mycompany.com/home/

# enable pretty url
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteBase /home/
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}/index.html !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}/index.php !-f
    RewriteRule . index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

Comment: Works ok for me. Do you have any other rewrite rules present? Possibly in other `.htaccess` files?

Comment: I'd say your `RewriteBase` near the bottom would be screwing up everything else for you

Comment: Hmm, but I tried placing the first section last (e.g. below it) and still didn't work... Does the `RewriteBase /home/` persist outside of the `<IfModule...>` tags?

Comment: It's not a matter of order. `RewriteBase` will affect everything to do with rewriting. You'd be better off putting a separate `.htaccess` file in your `/home` directory with those last set of rules (minus `RewriteBase` of course)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd remove that last block and put it in a separate `.htaccess` file in your `/home` directory, eg

```
# /home/.htaccess

<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    # not sure about the next 3 lines though
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}/index.html !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}/index.php !-f
    RewriteRule . index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

Comment: Seeing error in Chrome browser "webpage has a redirect loop: the webpage has resulted in too many redirects." I saw this error before making this change however, so it's not new based on Phil's recommendation here.

Comment: Nevermind, I mistakenly had some of the .htaccess lines of code commented out. My mistake. Now when it runs, the webpage loads